# Printing Scanned PDF and DJVU Documents

Tags: pdf, printer, printing, djvu

Earlier today, I was trying to print a scanned DJVU document, but it would always come out too faint. I had the same trouble when trying to print a scanned PDF document. Is it possible to make the print darker?

Thank you!

Comment: Not to sound hasty or impatient, but have I not provided enough information? I only ask, because that may be one's only reluctance to answer, that there is not enough information.

Comment: Many printers can be set to a "toner save" mode which will print fainter. Some other driver settings may have the same effect. Inkjets will print fainter on plain paper than on special inkjet paper. Please advise what printer and paper you are using, and what the driver settings are.

Comment: @hdhondt I am using the HP Officejet 6500 E709a Series fax; and I suppose I am using ordinary copy paper (?). How might I find out what my driver settings are?

Comment: Go to Printing Preferences or Properties. The exact location depends on your operating system. In any OS it should be visible when you try to print, if necessary after clicking a button. The OJ 6500 is an inkjet, so prints on plain paper will have a faded look. Try inkjet paper instead.